# Cakephp 3 : How to match md5 string in cakephp query ?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am sending a link like below

```
users/reset?token=0272dcff7439023e082204ac9fe9b96b
```

Where `token = user_email`

In controller after get token, I am trying to match this string with database email field.

I have tried by below code , but here query not working

```
public function search(){
  if($this->request->is(['post','get'])){
          $email   = $this->request->query('token');
          $query = $this->Users->find('all', [
                  'conditions' => [md5('Users.email') =>$email],
                  'fields'     => ['email','username']
                 ]);

  }
```

How can I match this md5 or base_64 string with email field in cake query ?

Comment: please try base64_encode($email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working when I have just change my code

```
'conditions' => [md5('Users.email') =>$email],
```

To

```
'conditions' => ['md5(Users.email)' =>$email],
```

Answer (score 0):

if your token as stored as `$token = md5($email);`

then you only need below code to retrieve the record

```
public function search(){
      if($this->request->is(['post','get'])){
              $email   = $this->request->query('token');
              $query = $this->Users->find('all', [
                      'conditions' => ['Users.email' =>$email], //hope you store email id as email not in md5
                      'fields'     => ['Users.email','Users.username']
                     ]);

      }
```

Because you can not set field md5.

Hope it will help you.

Thanks